# Change Texture mip map bias when importing Textures in the Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, mipmaps

In the import settings of each texture, the `Generate Mip Maps` option can be toggled, but there doesn't seem to be anything exposed related to configuring the number of mip map levels to be generated. Is it possible to change it from the default of 10?

I've read the documentation and couldn't find anything related to it. There is a `public` variable `Texture2D.mipMapCount` but it's `readonly`.

What I want to modify is the number of levels you can see here, highlighted in pink outline.

[image]

Comment: The-same answer as your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42498838/3785314) question. Please read that answer, take [`OnPreprocessTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPreprocessTexture.html) for Textures then modify the Textures when imported? Try that and update your question with the code you tried if there is a problem. Before posting very *similar* question again please do some research. The link I provided has some examples of how to do this.

Comment: @Programmer I don't think the number of mipmap levels is explicitly exposed in the API, is it? So even if the OP would get a proper TextureImporter set up, he still can't do what he wants.

Comment: @Bart From the Editor Inspector there is **no** such variable like *mipmap levels* or *mip map levels* so there *shouldn't* be one in the API. There are only *two* numerical variables relating to *mip maps* that can be set: *Aniso Level* which is an `int` type and the default value is 1 **not** 10 as the OP says. It can be accessed with `TextureImporter.anisoLevel`. Another variable(float) that can be changed but is not visible in the Editor is *mipMapBias* which can be accessed with `TextureImporter.mipMapBias`. Op did not mention any of these but I think he's looking for one of them.

Comment: I am guessing that the 10 the OP refers to is the number of levels you automatically get for a 1024x1024 texture. Which is of course a logical number for a texture that size.

Comment: @Programmer Yes, I am aware of the possibility of setting Aniso levels, but this isn't what defines the number of mip map levels you can have for a texture. It's a completely different setting. I've in fact reviewed the documentation for mip map levels and didn't find anything, concluding that it *can't* be modified. I'm just seeking validation with peers online, that maybe someone figured it out.

Comment: @Programmer Also pertaining to the other question as it's been mentioned, I have code solution for it I can share, just haven't the time yet to post it.

Comment: @Bart Didn't see notification for both. Check the updated question. I don't think that's what OP is looking for.